# need help fixing minor issues in my program

Tags: c++, rectangles

So here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Point
{
private:
    double px;
    double py;

public:
    void setX(const double x);
    void setY(const double y);
    double getX() const;
    double getY() const;
};

class Rectangle
{
private:
    string name;
    Point blPoint;
    double length, height;

public:
    // member functions
    void setName(const string & inName);
    void setBottomLeft(const double x, const double y);
    void setDimensions(const double inLength, const double inHeight);

    string getName() const;
    Point getBottomLeft() const;
    double getLength() const;
    double getHeight() const;

    double area() const;
    double perimeter() const;
    Point midPoint() const;
    void scaleBy2();
    void display() const;
};

// FUNCTION PROTOTYPES GO HERE:
void welcome();
bool read_rec(const string promptName, const string errorInvalid, const string errorUsed, string & inName, vector<Rectangle> & list);
void read_coord(const string promptPoint, double & x, double & y);
void read_length(const string promptLength, double & inLength, double & inHeight);
void add_rec(const string Name, double x, double y, double inLength, double inHeight, vector<Rectangle> & list);

int main()
{
    // Define your local variables, e.g. a vector of class Rectangle
    Rectangle rec;
    vector<Rectangle> list;
    string prompt1stName = "Enter the name of the first rectangle: ";
    string promptName = "Enter the name of the next rectangle: ";
    string errorInvalid = "Invalid input. Type 'rec' following by the name or 'stop' if done.";
    string errorUsed = "This name is already being used!";
    string inName;
    string Name;

    // Display welcome banner
welcome();

    /* Prompt user for first rectangle or 'stop' */
    bool read = read_rec(prompt1stName, errorInvalid, errorUsed, inName, list);

    // WHILE user input is invalid
    while (read == false)
    {

        // Display "Try again! "
 cout << "Try again! " << endl;
         read = read_rec(prompt1stName, errorInvalid, errorUsed, inName, list);
    }

    // IF user input is not 'stop'
        if (inName != "stop")
    {
        // Extract rectangle name from user input
                int a = inName.length() - 4;
        Name = inName.substr(4, a);

        // Prompt for bottom left point
                double x, y;
        string promptPoint = "Enter " + Name + "'s bottom left x and y coords: ";
        read_coord(promptPoint, x, y);

        // Prompt for length and height
                double inLength, inHeight;
        string promptLength = "Enter " + Name + "'s length and height: ";
        read_length(promptLength, inLength, inHeight);

        // Add rectangle to the rectangle list
        add_rec(Name, x, y, inLength, inHeight, list);
    }
    /* Prompt user for next rectangle or 'stop' */
    // WHILE user input not 'stop'
        while (inName != "stop")
    {
        // Display "Thank you! "
cout << "Thank you! ";
bool read = read_rec(promptName, errorInvalid, errorUsed, inName, list);

        // WHILE user input is invalid while (read == false)
        {

            // Display "Try again! "
                        cout << "Try again! " << endl;
            read = read_rec(promptName, errorInvalid, errorUsed, inName, list);
        }

            // IF user input is not 'stop'
                    if (inName != "stop")
        {

                // Extract rectangle name from user input
                            int a = inName.length() - 4;
            Name = inName.substr(4, a);

                // Prompt for bottom left point
                            double x, y;
            string promptPoint = "Enter " + Name + "'s bottom left x and y coords: ";
            read_coord(promptPoint, x, y);

                // Prompt for length and height
                            double inLength, inHeight;
            string promptLength = "Enter " + Name + "'s length and height: ";
            read_length(promptLength, inLength, inHeight);


                // Add rectangle to the rectangle list
            add_rec(Name, x, y, inLength, inHeight, list);
        }
    }

    // IF the rectangle list is not empty
        if (list.size() != 0)
    {
        // Display all rectangles in the rectangle list
int rec_num = 0;
int i = 1;
while (i< list.size())
{
    rec_num++;
    i++;

}
            cout << "You have " << rec_num+1 << " rectangle(s) in your list: ";
            cout << endl;

                for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
        {
            cout << "Rectangle '" << list[i].getName() << "' : ";
            list[i].display();
            list[i].scaleBy2();
            cout << "     After scale by 2: ";
            list[i].display();
            cout << endl;
        }
    }

    // ELSE
    else
        {
        // Display that no rectangles are in the list
                cout << "You have no rectangles in your list." << endl;
    }

  return 0;
}

// FUNCTION DEFINITIONS GO HERE:
void welcome()
{
    cout << "Welcome! Create your own list of rectangles." << endl;
    cout << "You will be asked to provide information about each rectangle in your list by name." << endl;
    cout << "Type the word 'stop' for the rectangle name when you are done." << endl;
    cout << endl;
}

bool read_rec(const string promptName, const string errorInvalid, const string errorUsed, string & inName, vector<Rectangle> & list)
{
    cout << promptName;
    getline(cin, inName);

    if (inName == "stop")
    {
        return(true);
    }
    else if (inName.substr(0,4) != "rec ")
    {
        cout << errorInvalid;
        return(false);
    }
    else
    {
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
        {
            if (inName == "rec " + list[i].getName())
            {
                j = j+1;
            }
        }
        if (j == 0)
        {
            return(true);
        }
        if (j != 0)
        {
            cout << errorUsed;
            return(false);
        }
    }
}

void read_coord(const string promptPoint, double & x, double & y)
{
    cout << promptPoint;
    cin >> x;
    cin >> y;
    }

void read_length(const string promptLength, double & inLength, double & inHeight)
{
    cout << promptLength;
    cin >> inLength;
    cin >> inHeight;
    cout << endl;

    while (inLength <= 0 || inHeight <= 0)
    {
        cout << "Make length and height positive values. Try again.";
        cout << promptLength;
        cin >> inLength;
        cin >> inHeight;
        cout << endl;
    }
}

void add_rec(const string Name, double x, double y, double inLength, double inHeight, vector<Rectangle> & list)
{
    Rectangle rec;
    rec.setName(Name);
    rec.setBottomLeft(x, y);
    rec.setDimensions(inLength, inHeight);
    list.push_back(rec);
}

// CLASS MEMBER FUNCTION DEFINITINOS GO HERE:

void Point::setX(const double x)
{
    px = x;
}

void Point::setY(const double y)
{
    py = y;
}

double Point::getX() const
{
    return (px);
}

double Point::getY() const
{
    return (py);
}

void Rectangle::setName(const string & inName)
{
    name = inName;
}

void Rectangle::setBottomLeft(const double x, const double y)
{
    blPoint.setX(x);
    blPoint.setY(y);
}

void Rectangle::setDimensions(const double inLength, const double inHeight)
{
    length = inLength;
    height = inHeight;
}

string Rectangle::getName() const
{
    return (name);
}

Point Rectangle::getBottomLeft() const
{
    return (blPoint);
}

double Rectangle::getLength() const
{
    return (length);
}

double Rectangle::getHeight() const
{
    return (height);
}

double Rectangle::area() const
{
    // area = length * height
    return(length * height);
}

double Rectangle::perimeter() const
{
    // perimeter = 2 * (length + height);
    return(2 * (length + height));
}

Point Rectangle::midPoint() const
{
    Point midPoint;
    double mx = blPoint.getX() + 0.5 * length;
    double my = blPoint.getY() + 0.5 * height;
    midPoint.setX(mx);
    midPoint.setY(my);
    return(midPoint);
}

void Rectangle::scaleBy2()
{
    double midx = blPoint.getX() + 0.5 * length;
    double midy = blPoint.getY() + 0.5 * height;
    double newblPx = midx - length;
    double newblPy = midy - height;
    length = 2*length;
    height = 2*height;
    blPoint.setX(newblPx);
    blPoint.setY(newblPy);
}

void Rectangle::display() const
{
    cout << " Location is (" << blPoint.getX() << ", " << blPoint.getY() << "), length is " << length << ", height is " << height << "; Area is " << area() << "; perimeter is " << perimeter() << ", midpoint is located at (" << midPoint().getX() << ", " << midPoint().getY() << ")" << endl;
}
```

The only problem's I now have with the program is that it always outputs "Invalid input. Type 'rec' following by the name or 'stop' if done.", and i do not know how to change this. And when you put in a duplicate answer as in rec fire and rec fire, it will say that rec fire is already being used and then continue to prompt for that rectangle instead of asking for another name. ANY HELP would be much appreciated!!

Comment: That is a lot of code and does not really fit with the Q&A style of this site, try http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/codereview-se

Comment: @mark: Careful how you phrase that- it can sound like you're saying "try Meta SO" ([which the OP did](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177082/need-help-fixing-minor-issues-in-my-program))

Comment: @arazan: Mark was suggesting you flag your post and ask for a moderator to move it to Code Review.

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong

```
/* Prompt user for first rectangle or 'stop' */
bool read = read_rec(prompt1stName, errorInvalid, errorUsed, inName, list);

// WHILE user input is invalid
while (read == false)
{

    // Display "Try again! "
    cout << "Try again! " << endl;
    bool read = read_rec(prompt1stName, errorInvalid, errorUsed, inName, list);
}
```

You have *two* read variables, the read variable in the while condition is referring to the read variable declared *first*, the read variable declared second is never used. What you want is this

```
/* Prompt user for first rectangle or 'stop' */
bool read = read_rec(prompt1stName, errorInvalid, errorUsed, inName, list);

// WHILE user input is invalid
while (read == false)
{

    // Display "Try again! "
    cout << "Try again! " << endl;
    read = read_rec(prompt1stName, errorInvalid, errorUsed, inName, list);
}
```

Now you have only one read variable. This accounts for the second error you describe I think.

Another way of coding this is like this

```
for (;;)
{
    bool read = read_rec(prompt1stName, errorInvalid, errorUsed, inName, list);
    if (read)
        break;
    cout << "Try again! " << endl;
}
```

In my view this kind of loop is better because it doesn't have the duplicated call to read_rec, so with this style of loop the mistake you made is impossible.

Comment: Thanks! That fixed that error, do you have any idea on how to fix it from outputting errorInvalid when it wasnt an invalid error? I believe that it is doing it because it does not = rec however the user is not inputting anything at this time.

Comment: Not sure, sorry. I would use a debugger to trace what is happening with your program step by step.

Comment: thanks for your help! I will download one now!